gt table not appear in for loop function after render to word
im trying to render a gt table into word file using quarto. but the result does not appear as a table. is there any way to fix this? below is my code and screenshot of word output
`
tbl_smry <- function(factor_ = 'manufacturer'){
  mpg %>% 
    rename(factor = factor_) %>% 
    group_by(year, factor) %>% 
    count() %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    gt()
  
}



for (x in c('manufacturer', 'model')) {
  tbl_smry(factor_ = x) %>% 
    print()
}

`
enter image description here
i expecting that it will appear in table format in the rendered word like below enter image description here

Perhaps How do I display gt tables created in a loop in RMarkdown Word output? answers your question?
